# convert x and y vector to meshgrid

Tags: matlab

I have an x, y, and z vector that I am currently using to create a 3-D scatter plot.  Is it possible to create a mesh plot using these three vectors?  I would prefer to only use these vectors and not alter any of my previous code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your terminology, but I'm assuming that you have unstructured surface data - `z` is the surface height for a set of positions `x, y`.

If you want to form a "mesh" for this data you could triangulate (via a Delauany triangulation of the positions):

```
t = delaunayn([x, y]);
```

If you want to visualise the "meshed" surface you can use `trimesh/trisurf`:

```
figure;
trimesh(t, x, y, z);
```